# Prevent freezing during reconstruction of complex WPF UI?

Tags: wpf, user-interface

OK lets face it, during render and a layout pass a WPF UI will freeze....

Any escape from this?

Someone talked about XAML serialization and Desrialization but does it really work? All I see is a momentary lapse and frozen window for complex UIs which are deserialized.

Will I ever be able to achieve swift UI loading?

**P.S.** I am not talking about loading view data on background thread and stuff. It is anyways a norm now-a-days. But is there **ANY** (this should sound desperate) way to not produce a hanged Window for complex UIs? By complex I mean heavy styles, deeply hierarchical templates, non virtualized panels etc.

Comment: Do you get it only in Visual Studio?  For me Visual Studio hangs some times but the .exe is pretty solid.  Visual Studio SP1 helped a lot.  A multiprocessor machine also helps.  For me it seems to hang building the visual tree some times.  If the XAML has an invalid binding name it seems like is get more hangs.  But if I let it sit for 1-5 minutes it works.   90% of the time is will load in 2-5 seconds.  I never leave in pages in a project that I am not using.

Comment: What about using the Dispatcher class with the low `Background` priority?

Comment: hmmm... probably I am so desperate because I hate to admit that I find that winforms dont hang for complex UIs (keeping aside data loading). :(

Comment: I am not an expert on this so take it with a grain of salt.  Where I have used serialization is to bind a UI element asynch to an object that derives from dispatcher as cannot bind a UI element to a dipather on another thread.   In that case I serialize to string so can bind asynch.  If there are components to the UI that are a lower priority then bind asynch.  And why are you NOT using virtualizing panels?  Work on getting you deep heiarchies to only get data on demand.

Comment: You mentioned not being able to use virtualization, that would have been my first choice.  I have resorted to pre-caching Views when the application starts up, keeping them as singletons and using them rather than creating new instances. Another thing i do is with complex tabbed Views, i only create the tab view instance when it is clicked, not when the tab control is started up

Comment: Do you experience problems during initialization or after loading? For the first case, there is a lot more you can do than the later.

Answer (score 2):

Given the fabula of your question you're expecting an answer from Rob Relyea at very least (not sure if he's still in). I wish we have a property PreventFreezing, set by someone rather carelessly to false. But we aren't. I think the only way to  look at the problem is to look at it on case per case basis. Some frameworks i.e. Prism and alikes sipmly aren't designed  to support smooth execution, and it's clearly stated in the description.

After 5+ years of dealing with WPF/SL I still have feeling that we're all working with a prototype, well designed one, but still a prototype. A lot of things are designed nicely, but designed to never meet performance deadlines.

I think, that 'Adding futures w/out caring too much about anything else' is a very natural stage in a lifecycle of any large probject. During this stage the number of futures grows expotentially, so the technical debt does. This is all good stuff as long as it gets followed by the technical debt repayment, which didn't seem to happen with WPF -i.e. performance review, syntax usability review and more.

Comment: Yes, WPF definitely still feels like a fairly detailed proof-of-concept rather than a finished polished framework.